# Can I run a script/extension to block/hide specific content on a page within Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'd really like to figure out how to either run a chunk of code or extension or something to block anything on a page that meets a certain criteria (in this case "Tebow").

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using google chrome extensions you have an access to DOM of the page, but you can't prevent some javascript code to be executed on the page while DOM is loading. This is because browser run inline javascripts once it added to the DOM. If your script start running, let's say on window.onload, then you have a chance to put your blocking logic before other scripts and remove them from the DOM, so they'll not be executed.
See more details about google chrome extensions here: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html

Answer (score 1):

This could may could be useful: http://techie-buzz.com/browsers/disable-javascript-images-cookies-in-google-chrome.html